# Euler-Lagrange Variational Calculus extreme condition for generic functional

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I need to do the following :

[image]

I saw for a simpler case, but I didn't understand the passage indicated by an arrow in the image below .

[image]

Why did the top integral become the bottom subtraction?

Now, I need to generalize to the case f(y, y', y'', x) , but I don't even understand the case for f(y, y', x).

Comment: This is integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood the passage. But I still don't know how to do the same for the case where we have y''(x).

Comment: You will need to integrate by parts twice. Hope that's enough of a hint!